# Embedding Tweets getting 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter, http-status-code-403

I'm embedding some Tweets on my page, but I'm getting:

```
GET https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/friendships/exists.json?user_a=19463349&screen_name_b=mrland_news&callback=twttr.setFriendshipExists 403 (Forbidden) follow_button.html:1
GET https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/friendships/exists.json?user_a=19463349&screen_name_b=BeautyBubble&callback=twttr.setFriendshipExists 403 (Forbidden) follow_button.html:1
```

in my developer console.  It only happens when I am logged in to Twitter when I log out I do not get any of these errors.  It looks like some widget is causing this from:

```
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

If I remove this line I don't get the errors but I also don't get any of the nice formatting of the Tweet.  Do I have to use OAuth?  I don't want to as it should be an anonymous app.

Edit:
I am not making that API call, I believe it is getting called from widgets.js.  I'm embedding the Tweet like this

```
`<blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
<p>This is a direct report from heaven! Or the ESPN 12 screen tv room at Sports Center   
<a href="http://t.co/qsoUuprP" title="http://twitter.com/jimcramer/status/260071104171876353/photo/1">twitter.com/jimcramer/stat…</a>
</p>&mdash; Jim Cramer (@jimcramer) 
<a href="https://twitter.com/jimcramer/status/260071104171876353" data-datetime="2012-10-21T17:32:38+00:00">October 21, 2012</a>
</blockquote>
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is related to the widget. When I try making both you API calls, I get this message as a response:

> Following information is not available for protected users without
>   authentication.

That is consistent with the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friendships/exists):

> Authentication is required if either user A or user B are protected.
>   Additionally the authenticating user must be a follower of the
>   protected user.

Comment: I am not making that API call though, I think something in the widgets.js is making it.  See edit.

Comment: I think he means the account is protected(?)